# Qual a função dos descritores em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Em Python existe o protocolo dos descritores que é, basicamente, definir uma classe para controlar o acesso aos atributos de outra, mas minha dúvida é, seria essa a real funcionalidade de um descritor, somente retirar da classe o trabalho de definir a lógica de acesso a seus atributos?

Aqui segue um *script*:

```
class Descriptor(object):

    def __init__(self, name = None):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, instance = None, owner = None):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        return instance.__dict__[self.name]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if len(value) < 3:
            raise ValueError
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        del instance.__dict__[self.name]


class Person(object):

    name = Descriptor('name')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A resposta a seguir foi baseada no artigo [*Descriptor HowTo Guide*](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/descriptor.html), escrito por Raymond Hettinger¹, na documentação oficial do Python.

## Definição e introdução

Em geral, um descritor é um atributo de objeto com comportamento de ligação cujo o acesso aos campos é sobrescrito por métodos do próprio descritor. Estes métodos são `__get__()`, `__set__()` e `__delete__()`. Se qualquer um desses métodos for definido pelo objeto, este pode ser chamado de descritor.

O comportamento padrão do Python para retornar um campo (*get*), atribuir a um campo (*set*) e excluir um campo (*delete*) é retorná-lo, atribuí-lo ou excluí-lo de um dicionário no objeto. Por exemplo, `a.x` buscará primeiro o valor de `x` em `a` com `a.__dict__['x']`, após buscará no tipo de `a` com `type(a).__dict__['x']` e assim por diante, através das classes bases de `a`, até chegar em `object`, excluindo as metaclasses. Se o valor encontrado para o campo `x` nesse processo for um objecto que implementa o protocolo de descrição (ser um descritor), o comportamento padrão será alterado para a invocação do método no descritor.

Descritor é um protocolo poderoso de uso geral. Ele é o mecanismo por traz das propriedades, métodos, métodos estáticos e `super()`, utilizado pela linguagem desde a versão 2.2 para definir as classes no *novo estilo*.

## Protocolo descritor

Como citado, o descritor é composto de três métodos, que possuem as seguintes estruturas:

- `descr.__get__(self, obj, type=None) -> value`
- `descr.__set__(self, obj, value) -> None`
- `descr.__delete__(self, obj) --> None`

E somente isso. Um objeto que define qualquer um desses métodos será considerado um descritor e poderá ser utilizado para sobrescrever o comportamento padrão do Python descrito acima.

Se um objeto define ambos os métodos `__get__()` e `__set__()` ele será considerado um descritor de dados (*data descriptors*). Por sua vez, descritores que definirem apenas `__get__()` serão chamados de descritores de *não-dados*² (*non-data descriptors*) - esse último geralmente utilizado para métodos, mas há outras possibilidades.

A diferença entre um descritor de dados e um descritor de *não-dados* é como será considerada a sobrescrita com respeito a uma entrada do dicionário da instância. Se o dicionário da instância possuir uma entrada com o mesmo nome que um descritor de dados, o descritor de dados terá precedência. Porém, se o dicionário possuir uma entrada com mesmo nome que um descritor de *não-dados*, o dicionário terá precedência.

Para definir um descritor de apenas leitura, basta definir ambos os métodos `__get__()` e `__set__()` levantando uma exceção `AttributeError` em `__set__()`.

## Invocando um descritor

Um descritor pode ser chamado diretamente através do método. Por exemplo, `d.__get__(obj)`, onde `d` é o descritor e `obj` o objeto descrito.

Alternativamente, é muito mais comum um descritor ser chamado através do acesso a campos. Por exemplo, `obj.d` buscará por `d` no dicionário de `obj`; se for um descritor, definindo o método `__get__()`, então o Python chamará `d.__get__(obj)`, considerando as regras de precedência, obviamente.

Detalhes da invocação dependem se `obj` é uma instância ou uma classe.

Para instâncias, a lógica se encontra em `object.__getattribute__()`, que transforma a chamada `b.x` em `type(b).__dict__['x'].__get__(b, type(b))`. A implementação trabalha sobre a cadeia de precedência que define que descritores de dados possuem precedência sobre variáveis de instâncias, mas estas possuem precedência sobre descritores de *não-dados*. Para mais detalhes, ver o código fonte de [`PyObject_GenericGetAttr()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_GenericGetAttr) em [`Objects/object.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.6/Objects/object.c).

Para classes, a lógica se encontra em `type.__getattribute__()`, que transforma a  chamada `B.x` em `B.__dict__['x'].__get__(None, B)`. Em Python puro, se assemelha a:

```
def __getattribute__(self, key):
    "Emulate type_getattro() in Objects/typeobject.c"
    v = object.__getattribute__(self, key)
    if hasattr(v, '__get__'):
        return v.__get__(None, self)
    return v
```

Os pontos importantes para lembrar são:

- Descritores são chamados através do método `__getattribute__()`;
- Sobrescrever o método `__getattribute__()` previne chamadas automáticas de descritores;
- `object.__getattribute__()` e `type.__getattribute__()` fazem chamadas diferentes a `__get__()`;
- Descritores de dados sempre sobrescreve o comportamento do dicionário da instância;
- Descritores de *não-dados* podem ser sobrescritos pelo dicionário da instância;

O objeto `super()` possui uma implementação personalizada de `__getattribute__()` para chamar descritores. A chamada `super(B, obj)` buscará em `obj.__class__.__mro__` a classe base `A` que imediatamente segue `B` e então retorna `A.__dict__['m'].__get__(obj, B)`. Se não for um descritor, `m` será retornado sem modificações; se não estiver no dicionário, `m` será revertido para uma busca em `object.__getattribute__()`.

## Exemplo

O código a seguir define uma classe cujos objetos serão descritores de dados que exibem uma mensagem quando vosso valor é retornado ou definido. Sobrescrever o método `__getattribute__` seria uma abordagem interessante para implementar a mesma lógica para todos os campos, porém, com o descritor, será possível definir quais os campos que serão monitorados.

```
class RevealAccess(object):
    """A data descriptor that sets and returns values
       normally and prints a message logging their access.
    """

    def __init__(self, initval=None, name='var'):
        self.val = initval
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        print('Retrieving', self.name)
        return self.val

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        print('Updating', self.name)
        self.val = val

class MyClass(object):
    x = RevealAccess(10, 'var "x"')
    y = 5
```

Assim, fazemos:

```
>>> m = MyClass()
>>> m.x
Retrieving var "x"
10
>>> m.x = 20
Updating var "x"
>>> m.x
Retrieving var "x"
20
>>> m.y
5
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/ForestgreenMarriedGravity) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/eNkRyx) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/de739e280e6206b461db4fb08aa00ce9)</sup>

## Propriedades

A forma mais fácil de se implementar o descritor no Python é utilizando uma propriedade.

```
property(fget=None, fset=None, fdel=None, doc=None) -> property attribute
```

A própria documentação dá um exemplo de como fazer:

```
class C(object):
    def getx(self): return self.__x
    def setx(self, value): self.__x = value
    def delx(self): del self.__x
    x = property(getx, setx, delx, "I'm the 'x' property.")
```

Inclusive, a implementação equivalente da propriedade em Python puro é exatamente a implementação de um descritor de dados:

```
class Property(object):
    "Emulate PyProperty_Type() in Objects/descrobject.c"

    def __init__(self, fget=None, fset=None, fdel=None, doc=None):
        self.fget = fget
        self.fset = fset
        self.fdel = fdel
        if doc is None and fget is not None:
            doc = fget.__doc__
        self.__doc__ = doc

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        if self.fget is None:
            raise AttributeError("unreadable attribute")
        return self.fget(obj)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if self.fset is None:
            raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")
        self.fset(obj, value)

    def __delete__(self, obj):
        if self.fdel is None:
            raise AttributeError("can't delete attribute")
        self.fdel(obj)

    def getter(self, fget):
        return type(self)(fget, self.fset, self.fdel, self.__doc__)

    def setter(self, fset):
        return type(self)(self.fget, fset, self.fdel, self.__doc__)

    def deleter(self, fdel):
        return type(self)(self.fget, self.fset, fdel, self.__doc__)
```

## Funções e métodos

Dicionários de classes armazenam as referências aos métodos como funções. Na definição de uma classe, métodos são definidos usando `def` ou `lambda`, que são as ferramentas de criação de funções. Métodos só se diferenciam de funções normais por causa de seu primeiro argumento, que é exclusivo para o objeto instância da classe.

Para suportar a chamada de métodos, funções definem o método `__get__()` para ligar o método à instância durante a chamada. Isto significa que todas as funções são descritores de *não-dados* que retornam um método ligado quando chamadas de um objeto.

Em Python puro, a função seria algo como:

```
class Function(object):
    . . .
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        "Simulate func_descr_get() in Objects/funcobject.c"
        if obj is None:
            return self
        return types.MethodType(self, obj)
```

## Métodos estáticos e de classe

Descritores de *não-dados* definem um mecanismo simples para variações nos padrões usuais que fazem a ligação de funções para métodos. Por exemplo, descritores de *não-dados* convertem a chamada `obj.f(*args)` em `f(obj, *args)` e `klass.f(*args)` em `f(*args)`.

O quadro abaixo apresenta todas as transformações para os diversos casos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>Quadro: exemplifica as transformações de uma função, um método estático e um método de classe quando invocados de um objeto e uma classe.</sup>

Métodos estáticos retornam a própria função, sem modificações. Chamando tanto `c.f` ou `C.f` o equivalente será `object.__getattribute__(c, 'f')` ou `object.__getattribute__(C, 'f')`. Como resultado, não faz diferença invocar um método estático de um objeto ou de uma classe.

A implementação equivalente em Python puro seria:

```
class StaticMethod(object):
    "Emulate PyStaticMethod_Type() in Objects/funcobject.c"

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        return self.f
```

A diferença para um método de classe é que este refere a referência da classe como parâmetro, mas igualmente não faz diferença ao invocá-lo de um objeto ou de uma classe. A implementação equivalente em Python puro seria:

```
class ClassMethod(object):
    "Emulate PyClassMethod_Type() in Objects/funcobject.c"

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __get__(self, obj, klass=None):
        if klass is None:
            klass = type(obj)
        def newfunc(*args):
            return self.f(klass, *args)
        return newfunc
```

## Considerações finais

> O protocolo dos descritores consiste basicamente em definir uma classe para controlar o acesso aos atributos de outra, mas minha dúvida é, seria essa a real funcionalidade de um descritor?

Sim, com o protocolo de descritor, você transfere a responsabilidade de regras de negócio sobre um campo para outra classe. Desta forma, você mantém a classe original focada na sua própria responsabilidade e deixa detalhes sobre os seus campos para uma classe específica.

Mas, perceba que, como é um protocolo de uso geral, seu uso não possui limitação. A linguagem Python define todas as funções como sendo descritores; métodos são descritores, métodos estáticos e de classe são descritores; propriedades são descritores; e vai além.

Uma aplicação, por exemplo, seria para um campo idade, que não faz sentido possuir valores negativos, então pode-se definir um descritor para este campo:

```
class Pessoa:
    @property
    def idade(self):
        return self._idade

    @idade.setter
    def idade(self, value):
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError('Idade não pode ser negativa')
        self._idade = value
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/ShinyHorizontalDesigners) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/nGco4y) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/845671bdb975fd567c0d8ee3f2f607be)</sup>

Basicamente criamos um descritor de dados que validará o valor antes de atribuí-lo ao campo. Seria o mesmo que fazer:

```
class Idade(object):
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        return self.value

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        if val < 0:
            raise ValueError
        self.value = val

class Pessoa(object):
    idade = Idade(30)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/FinancialMagnificentBracket) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/AmnPX1) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/306a4b40f1bdb16ba613d4622ee266d7)</sup>

Mas qual seria a vantagem de implementar uma classe ao invés de apenas definir uma propriedade? Reutilização de código. Ao invés de definir o descritor `Idade`, poderia ser definido o descritor `Positive`, que faz a validação de números negativos e utilizá-lo, por exemplo, em dados de uma data, dia, mês e ano, que também não são negativos (geralmente).

---

<sup>1: Se há uma pessoa que você precisa seguir (não fisicamente) para aprender Python, Raymond Hettinger é essa pessoa.</sup>

<sup>2: Não achei uma tradução fiel para *non-data*, então deixei *não-dados*.</sup>