# Por que instâncias de descritores no Python devem ser atributos de classe?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, python-internals

Estou estudando `descritores` em Python e me deparei que os mesmos devem ser implementados como `atributos de classe` por exemplo:

```
class Descriptor:

    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
       print('Acessando o __get__')
       return self.obj


class Grok:

    attr = Descriptor('value')

# Output
>>> g = Grok()
>>> g.attr
Acessando o __get__
value
```

Dessa forma o mesmo funciona, mas se eu fizer dessa forma:

```
class Grok:

    def __init__(self, attr):
        self.attr = Descriptor(attr)


# Output
>>> g = Grok('value')
>>> g.attr
<__main__.Descriptor at 0x7fe5bca77550>
```

Não funciona dessa forma, minha dúvida é: Por quê?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Como comentado em [Qual a função dos descritores em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/303982/5878) existe uma ordem de chamadas que o interpretador executa quando você faz `g.attr`. Como `g`, nesse caso, é uma instância, o interpretador irá executar `g.__getattribute__('attr')`. Em Python, o que o interpretador irá tentar acessar é:

```
type(g).__dict__['attr'].__get__(g, type(g))
```

Ou seja, buscará o valor de `attr` na classe de `g`, não em `g` diretamente. Isso explica porque funciona quando o descritor é um atributo de classe, mas não é suficiente para demonstrar que não funciona para atributo de instância. Para tal, iremos mais a fundo no código e analisar o código em C que é executado.

A implementação em C do método `__getattribute__` é descrito por [PyObject_GenericGetAttr](https://docs.python.org/3.6/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_GenericGetAttr) que é implementado em [Objects/object.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/object.c#L1125). Vamos analisar aos poucos.

A função é:

```c
PyObject *
PyObject_GenericGetAttr(PyObject *obj, PyObject *name)
{
    return _PyObject_GenericGetAttrWithDict(obj, name, NULL);
}
```

E, assim, devemos analisar a implementação de [`_PyObject_GenericGetAttrWithDict`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/object.c#L1037).

```c
PyObject *
_PyObject_GenericGetAttrWithDict(PyObject *obj, PyObject *name, PyObject *dict)
{
    PyTypeObject *tp = Py_TYPE(obj);
    PyObject *descr = NULL;
    PyObject *res = NULL;
    descrgetfunc f;
    Py_ssize_t dictoffset;
    PyObject **dictptr;

    ...
}
```

Informações importantes para continuarmos:

1. A função recebe como parâmetro `obj`, uma referência ao objeto `g`;
2. A função recebe como parâmetro `name`, nome do atributo acessado;
3. A função recebe como parâmetro `dict`, um dicionário que, neste caso, será nulo;
4. A partir de `obj` buscasse a referência ao seu tipo, `Grok`, pela variável `tp`;
5. Inicializa ponteiros nulos `descr`, que será um possível descritor, `res`, o retorno da função, `f`, a função `__get__` do possível descritor, assim como outros ponteiros;

A partir disso é validado o nome do atributo acessado, retornando um erro se o atributo não for uma *string*. Se for, incrementa o número de referências ao objeto com `Py_INCREF`.

```c
if (!PyUnicode_Check(name)){
    PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                 "attribute name must be string, not '%.200s'",
                 name->ob_type->tp_name);
    return NULL;
}
Py_INCREF(name);
```

Após, é validado o dicionário interno do tipo de `g`, `tp`, finalizando a função em caso de falha:

```c
if (tp->tp_dict == NULL) {
    if (PyType_Ready(tp) < 0)
        goto done;
}
```

Após, é buscado pelo atributo na classe de `g`, `Grok`, salvando em `descr`. Se encontrado, incrementa-se as referências e é definido o valor de `f` como sendo a função `__get__` do valor encontrado em `descr`. Se encontrar a função e o descritor for um descritor de dados (possui o método `__set__`), define-se `res` como resultado de `__get__` e finaliza-se a função:

```
descr = _PyType_Lookup(tp, name);

f = NULL;
if (descr != NULL) {
    Py_INCREF(descr);
    f = descr->ob_type->tp_descr_get;
    if (f != NULL && PyDescr_IsData(descr)) {
        res = f(descr, obj, (PyObject *)obj->ob_type);
        goto done;
    }
}
```

> A função que verifica se é um descritor de dados, `PyDescr_IsData`, é definida por
>
> ```
> #define PyDescr_IsData(d) (Py_TYPE(d)->tp_descr_set != NULL)
> ```
>
> Que basicamente verifica se existe o método `__set__` no objeto.

E é até aqui que é executado quando o descritor (de dados) é um atributo de classe. Para um atributo de instância, a execução continua. Agora, como trabalharemos direto com a instância, será necessário considerar também o dicionário interno dela. Assim, o próximo passo executado será a união entre os dicionários da instância e da classe, sendo armazenado o ponteiro final em `dict`:

```
if (dict == NULL) {
    /* Inline _PyObject_GetDictPtr */
    dictoffset = tp->tp_dictoffset;
    if (dictoffset != 0) {
        if (dictoffset < 0) {
            Py_ssize_t tsize;
            size_t size;

            tsize = ((PyVarObject *)obj)->ob_size;
            if (tsize < 0)
                tsize = -tsize;
            size = _PyObject_VAR_SIZE(tp, tsize);
            assert(size <= PY_SSIZE_T_MAX);

            dictoffset += (Py_ssize_t)size;
            assert(dictoffset > 0);
            assert(dictoffset % SIZEOF_VOID_P == 0);
        }
        dictptr = (PyObject **) ((char *)obj + dictoffset);
        dict = *dictptr;
    }
}
```

Depois disso, será buscado pelo atributo no dicionário `dict` e, se encontrar, é retornado o valor:

```
if (dict != NULL) {
    Py_INCREF(dict);
    res = PyDict_GetItem(dict, name);
    if (res != NULL) {
        Py_INCREF(res);
        Py_DECREF(dict);
        goto done;
    }
    Py_DECREF(dict);
}
```

Perceba que aqui, como o atributo de instância existirá no dicionário, o valor retornado em `PyDict_GetItem` será a instância do decorador que, como será diferente de nula, será retornada, sem considerar se existe, ou não, o método `__get__` definido.

Se não encontrar o atributo no dicionário da instância, será verificado se o descritor encontrado na classe é um descritor de *não-dados* (que não possui o método `__set__`) e, se existir, é chamado:

```
if (f != NULL) {
    res = f(descr, obj, (PyObject *)Py_TYPE(obj));
    goto done;
}
```

Após, se ainda não satisfez nenhuma das condições anteriores, é verificado se o objeto `descr` é diferente de nulo (achou alguma coisa sobre o atributo no tipo de `g`), então define-se `descr` como sendo o resultado e o retorna:

```
if (descr != NULL) {
    res = descr;
    descr = NULL;
    goto done;
}
```

E, finalmente, se nada deu certo até agora, retorna o erro de atributo não encontrado:

```
PyErr_Format(PyExc_AttributeError,
             "'%.50s' object has no attribute '%U'",
             tp->tp_name, name);
```

Para finalizar, mexe-se nas quantidades de referências e retorna-se o valor de `res`:

```
done:
    Py_XDECREF(descr);
    Py_DECREF(name);
    return res;
```

A função inteira, para melhor visualização é:

```
PyObject *
_PyObject_GenericGetAttrWithDict(PyObject *obj, PyObject *name, PyObject *dict)
{
    PyTypeObject *tp = Py_TYPE(obj);
    PyObject *descr = NULL;
    PyObject *res = NULL;
    descrgetfunc f;
    Py_ssize_t dictoffset;
    PyObject **dictptr;

    if (!PyUnicode_Check(name)){
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                     "attribute name must be string, not '%.200s'",
                     name->ob_type->tp_name);
        return NULL;
    }
    Py_INCREF(name);

    if (tp->tp_dict == NULL) {
        if (PyType_Ready(tp) < 0)
            goto done;
    }

    descr = _PyType_Lookup(tp, name);

    f = NULL;
    if (descr != NULL) {
        Py_INCREF(descr);
        f = descr->ob_type->tp_descr_get;
        if (f != NULL && PyDescr_IsData(descr)) {
            res = f(descr, obj, (PyObject *)obj->ob_type);
            goto done;
        }
    }

    if (dict == NULL) {
        /* Inline _PyObject_GetDictPtr */
        dictoffset = tp->tp_dictoffset;
        if (dictoffset != 0) {
            if (dictoffset < 0) {
                Py_ssize_t tsize;
                size_t size;

                tsize = ((PyVarObject *)obj)->ob_size;
                if (tsize < 0)
                    tsize = -tsize;
                size = _PyObject_VAR_SIZE(tp, tsize);
                assert(size <= PY_SSIZE_T_MAX);

                dictoffset += (Py_ssize_t)size;
                assert(dictoffset > 0);
                assert(dictoffset % SIZEOF_VOID_P == 0);
            }
            dictptr = (PyObject **) ((char *)obj + dictoffset);
            dict = *dictptr;
        }
    }
    if (dict != NULL) {
        Py_INCREF(dict);
        res = PyDict_GetItem(dict, name);
        if (res != NULL) {
            Py_INCREF(res);
            Py_DECREF(dict);
            goto done;
        }
        Py_DECREF(dict);
    }

    if (f != NULL) {
        res = f(descr, obj, (PyObject *)Py_TYPE(obj));
        goto done;
    }

    if (descr != NULL) {
        res = descr;
        descr = NULL;
        goto done;
    }

    PyErr_Format(PyExc_AttributeError,
                 "'%.50s' object has no attribute '%U'",
                 tp->tp_name, name);
  done:
    Py_XDECREF(descr);
    Py_DECREF(name);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Tem mais algumas coisas que é necessário comentar. Vejo se consigo ainda essa noite, se ninguém responder antes.

Comment: Agradeço pela resposta.

Answer (score 4):

A outra resposta está muito boa - inclusive com trechos de código da implementação de referência. Mas vou escrever uma resposta mais curta aqui, abordando um outro aspecto da questão.

Acho que pode-se pensar nisso como um "guia" pra entender vários dos comportamentos da linguagem - que, na minha opinião, é muito agradável pro que trás pouquíssimas surpresas uma vez que você entenda esses guias.

Em Python, toda a funcionalidade "mágica"  - ou seja - métodos que são chamados de forma transparente pela própria linguagem - está amarrada a atributos da classe, não das instâncias.

Sim, pra facilidade de reconhecimento, e evitar coincidência de nomes, essas funcionalidades também são, em geral, denotadas por nomes que começam e terminam com um underscore duplo - os famosos  `__dunder__`.

Mas então, uma das razões pelas quais se optou por esse comportamento é isso: descriptors implicam em comportamento especial para acesso ao atributo - assim, como os atributos `__len__`, `__init__`, etc...  são especiais - e por isso tem que ser definidos na classe.

A partir dessa motivação que é  mais um "feeling", aí vem razões práticas, como implementação - o acesso de atributos numa instância funciona a partir de um dicionário normal - esse mecanismo teria que ser mudado pra que ao recuperar um atributo da instância, em vez de entregar esse atributo, alguma outra operação fosse feita.

E - como o descriptor seria "instalado" numa instância pra começar? Ia ficar estranho, no primeiro acesso de `objeto.attr = MeuDescriptor()`  é feito um *assignment* normal, e a partir daí, nos acessos seguitnes `objeto.attr = ...`, em vez de se colocar o atributo no `__dict__` da instância, o método `__set__` do descriptor seria chamado.  Isso seria colocar uma depêndencia de estado nas operações de assignment que tem potencial para complicar muito o código - ja que o que um assigment faz dependeria da ordem de execução.

Tanto é que mesmo que uma implementação de descriptor (na classe mesmo) *permite* que você escreva código que faz coisas diferentes dependendo da ordem em que valores são atribuidos ao descriptor: é só manter uma variável de estado controlada pelo descriptor. Mas isso não é usado em quase nenhum caso.

## por fim

Essa é a opção de implementação, mas a linguagem é dinâmica o suficiente para permitir que você faça suas próprias classes que funcionem com "descriptors na instância" - e nem daria tanto trabalho. Basta fazer uma classe base definindo os métodos `__getattribute__` e `__setattr__` para trabalharem com descriptors.  (e claro, o efeito maluco que eu mencionei acima ficaria valendo).

Para funcionar só com "readonly" seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
class InstanceDescriptableBase:
    def __getattribute__(self, attrname):
        attr = super().__getattribute__(attrname)
        if hasattr(attr, "__get__"):
            attr = attr.__get__(self, self.__class__)
        return attr
```

E no terminal:

```
In [3]: class D:
   ...:     def __get__(self, instace, owner):
   ...:         return 42
   ...:     

In [4]: class Test(InstanceDescriptableBase):
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         self.attr = D()
   ...:         

In [5]: t = Test()

In [6]: t.attr
Out[6]: 42
```

Comment: Era algo assim que eu queria complementar na resposta, mas imaginei que logo você responderia :D

Comment: Hahahaha! Tem alguns assuntos que não resisto mesmo. Ainda estou me segurando pra não escrever o código na pergunta sobre abstract static methods de ontem.